# Return statement doesn't break out of block, even though condition is true

Tags: java, math, return, fibonacci

This is a simple program to check if a number if Fibonnacci. I have a mysterious bug: the "return true" statement isn't triggered. Instead, "hi" will be printed many times. Return should break out of the method, does anyone have insight as to why it's not? Thanks!

```
import java.util.*;
public class Solution {

public static boolean listFibs (long oldestFib, long oldFib, long input) {
    long newFib = oldestFib + oldFib;

    while (newFib < Math.pow(10,10)) {

        if (newFib == input) {
            System.out.println("hi");
            return true;
        }

        listFibs(oldFib, newFib, input);
    }

    return false;  
}


public static void main(String[] args) {
    /*Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    int testCases = in.nextInt();
    for (int i = 0; i < testCases; i++) {
        int a = in.nextInt();
        System.out.println("A=  " + a);
        System.out.println(listFibs(0, 1, a));
    }*/

    System.out.println(listFibs(0, 1, 5));
```

}
}

Comment: Yeah-- I tried it both in the hackerrank environment and my local IDE. Does it work for you?

Comment: Math.pow 10 10 is always 10 pow 10, what are you trying there?

Comment: Only checking numbers up to 10^10.

Comment: tell us your whole algorithm in english?

Comment: I am almost certain that the problem is with your while loop, because if the newfib != input, then it will create 10^10 instances of same function with same input. You should replace while with if and that should be good.

Comment: what is input, what if it is or it isnt a fib?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Due to the recursion there are many incarnations of `listFibs`. The `return` just leaves one of them.

In the example given, you get the following calls:

```
listFib(0,1,5)
  listFib(1,1,5)
    listFib(1,2,5)
      listFib(2,3,5)
      -> true
      listFib(2,3,5) // called again due to the loop
      -> true
      listFib(2,3,5) // called again due to the loop
      -> true
      listFib(2,3,5) // called again due to the loop
      -> true
      listFib(2,3,5) // called again due to the loop
      ...
```

Comment: Can you explain further? I thought the return statement would prevent it from calling itself again once it became true.

Comment: Thats the point. It will not call itself anymore, but there instances of that function that will.

Comment: Recursion is a "nesting" of methods. Each instance of listFibs is different, and will perform its function even if others have returned.

Recursion can be confusing, you should check out some documentation ... 

Try http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/23recursion/

Comment: Does this mean doing it recursively would take twice as long as a non-recursive method?

Answer (score 0):

actually, if "hi" is printed many times, the return statement must be executed the same time. if you install a break point in that return statement, you will see.
your function is a `recursion`, and "listFibs" will be called many times.

Answer (score 0):

Print values of all 3 variables in the method and you will know what's wrong. You are using recursion, see how many times it's being called.

Also, after call to `listFib`, execution will go to while loop again. You need to say `return listFibs` at least. Between your `listFibs` and while loop condition, nothing is changing. 2,3,5 are being found again and again.

see http://ideone.com/1d440f

Comment: Right- but return true should break out of the method, so the recursive call wouldn't happen once the fibonacci number was found?

Comment: recursion is like a tree, once it find a leaf, it has to unwind from there

Answer (score 0):

You are one step short... The recursive call doesn't do anything with the results you get from listFibs, so the program sees something like this:

```
while (newFib < Math.pow(10,10)) {

    if (newFib == input) {
        System.out.println("hi");
        return true;
    }

    true //or false
}
```

Try adding this extra little IF statement. Once a true result is found it will be passed back up the chain and out of the function.

```
while (newFib < Math.pow(10,10)) {

    if (newFib == input) {
        System.out.println("hi");
        return true;
    }

    if listFibs(oldFib, newFib, input){
        return true;
    }
}
```